# open the app through intent filter is not working

Tags: android

I have using the following code in the android manifest file,but its not open the application.

```
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityIntroScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="market" android:host="details" android:path="" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Where is the miss take...

Comment: Can you see the application's icon in the launcher? Or it doesn't appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to to single intent-filters. have a look here: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml